# Laravel event broadcasting with socketio and redis is not working in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to show realtime message notification count when user logged in to the website. For this I am using  socketio, redis and laravel event. But it is not working. In laravel log I am getting a message. In this message `count` is showing but `socket` is null. I think I miss something. My gitbash showing channel subscribed and user is connected.

**Gitbash**

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/cabinapi$ node socket.js
    listening on *:3000
    Redis: message-channel subscribed
    a user connected
```

**Laravel log**

```
[2017-09-28 07:21:57] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\MessageEvent] on channels [message-channel] with payload:
{
    "count": 9,
    "socket": null
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function privateMessageAPICount($id)
{
        $count = PrivateMessage::where('receiver_id', new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id))
            ->where('read', 0)
            ->count();

        if ($count > 0){
            event(new MessageEvent($count));
        }
}
```

**routes->web.php**

```
Route::get('/message/count/{id}', 'Cabinowner\DashboardController@privateMessageAPICount');
```

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://cabinapi.app
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**MessageEvent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class MessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $count;
    public function __construct($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['message-channel'];
    }
}
```

**views->owner->layouts->app.blade.php**

```
<body>
<span class="label label-success msgSpan"><span class="msgCountRemove">{!! $miscellaneous->privateMessageCount() !!}</span></span>

<script src="{{ asset('plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('{{ env("APP_URL") }}:3000');
        socket.on('message-channel:App\\Events\\MessageEvent', function(data){
            $('.msgCountRemove').remove();
            $('.msgSpan').append('<span class="msgCountRemove">'+data.count+'</span>');
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

**config->app.php**

```
'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```

**socket.js**

```
var app   = require('express')();
var http  = require('http').Server(app);
var io    = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('message-channel', function () {
    console.log('Redis: message-channel subscribed');
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Redis: Message on ' + channel + ' received!');
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: where do you get that log? can you check config/broadcasting.php? maybe you set broadcast driver to log there so .env is not working?

Comment: @HanlinWang, Log I got from storage->logs->laravel.log. No I didn't set broadcast to log. `'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),`

Comment: I tested your code in my local, it's all working, and yes socket is null, that's log from console with your socket.js `{"event":"App\\Events\\MessageEvent","data":{"count":1,"socket":null},"socket":null}
` so you didn't receive log like this, right?

Comment: @HanlinWang, My problem is count is not updating in my view

Comment: so you can receive event on FE, just js code didn't update your html, right?

Comment: @HanlinWang, What is FE? Js code didn't update my html.

Comment: did you receive data in js? try console.log(data), is there any other error shown in console?

Comment: @HanlinWang, Showing nothing.

Comment: @HanlinWang, Is this because of Redis problem? If so how can we check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not found the exact reason why it is not working in laravel 5.4. 
But I have added some changes. Now I am getting realtime message notification count. I have listed below what are the changes I have done.

I fully done realtime notification count with the help of `redis` and `socketio`

**socket.js (`Removed ioredis and included redis`)**

```
var redis = require('redis');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');
    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message){
       console.log('new message in queue', channel, message);
       socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        redisClient.quit();
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->publish('message', $message);
```

**views->owner->layouts->app.blade.php**

```
<script>
        var socket = io('{{ env("APP_URL") }}:3000');
        socket.on('message-channel:App\\Events\\MessageEvent', function(data){
            $('.msgCountRemove').remove();
            $('.msgSpan').append('<span class="msgCountRemove">'+data+'</span>');
        });
    </script>
```

**Removed MessageEvent.php**

Comment: you are not using event broadcasting you are simply publishing to redis what I am facing same issue and would like to use even() helper instead for Redis::publish()